# Graphics card is not working

Tags: graphics-card

My computer has been crashing a lot lately and usually it just turns back on with out problem. It had turned off and I got tired of it so I went to sleep.

This morning I turn it on but the monitor had no connection and stayed asleep. So I took out the RAM and unplugged all cords from the computer and even took out the CMOS battery and let sit for about 30 minutes. I go back plug everything back in still no luck.

So I took the Graphics card out and took off the heat sink and dusted everything off in and out of the computer making sure nothing was blocked by dust or anything else. Put everything back together plugged everything back in and still no luck.

The CPU fan and case fans still spin but the Graphics card does not. I think I may have even smelled a burning smell but it might have just been my imagination.

If any advise can be given before I go off and buy a new GPU that would be great.

[Part list](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/NmXvqs) of everything in the computer.

Answer (score -1):

Get Liquid Cooling, because it sounds like your overcooked component die of not staying below the Critical Temperature set by your manufacturer.  There are [Water Cooling Systems](http://www.frozencpu.com/cat/l1/g30/Liquid_Cooling.html) that should aid in prevention of your next part replacement.  I would also suggest Liquid cooling the entire system and installing sensors to make certain you know what exactly the temperature is.

Comment: "Get Liquid Cooling"? I doubt getting a liquid cooling system will fix a burnt out graphics card.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Please carefully read what I said.